Maximum area of triangle with one side and one angle known

In a triangle $ABC$ , smallest side is $13$ and other $2$ sides are also integer and angle satisfy the relation $\displaystyle \sin^2(A)+\sin^2(B)+\sin^2(C)=2,$ Then largest possible area of triangle ABC, Where $A,B,C$ are angle of triangle.

What I try : $\displaystyle 1-\sin^2(A)+1-\sin^2(B)-\sin^2(C)=0$
$\displaystyle \cos^2(A)+\cos^2(B)-\sin^2(C)=0$
$\displaystyle 2\cos^2(A)+2\cos^2(B)-2\sin^2(C)=0$
$\displaystyle 1+\cos(2A)+1+\cos(2B)-1+\cos(2C)=0$
$\displaystyle 2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)+2\cos^2(C)=0$
$\displaystyle 2\cos(\pi-C)\cos(A-B)+2\cos^2(C)=0$
$\displaystyle -2\cos(C)\bigg[\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+C)\bigg]=0$
$\displaystyle 4\cos(A)\cos(B)\cos(C)=0$
Means one angle must be $\displaystyle 90^\circ$
Let angle $C$ is $90^\circ$
Then we have given one side length $13$ and let other side $x$ and angle between them $90^\circ$
So area of triangle $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2}(13)(x)\sin(90^\circ)=\frac{13x}{2}$
Now how can I find $x$ so that area is maximum , please have a look , Thanks

Once you establish that one of the angles is $90^\circ$, what remains to be done is just find integer-length right triangles with smallest side-length being $13$. There are not many!

Since the smallest side has length $13$, we know that this cannot be the hypotenuse of the triangle.  So the triangle is a Pythagorean triple with the shortest leg having length $13$.  Moreover, since $13$ is prime, such a triple is primitive:  hence we must have coprime positive integers $m, n$ such that
$$\begin{align}13 = a &= m^2 - n^2, \\
b &= 2mn, \\
c &= m^2 + n^2.
\end{align}$$
Since $m^2 - n^2 = (m+n)(m-n) = 13$, it follows that $m = n+1$ and $m + n = 13$, i.e. $m = 7$ and $n = 6$.  This leads to the unique triple
$$(a,b,c) = (13, 84, 85).$$

Hint:
Replacing  $13$ with $p,$ where $p(>2)$ is any prime
If $C=90^\circ,$ for $a\le b<c,a=p$  we have  $c^2=p^2+b^2$
$\implies p^2=(c+b)(c-b)$
As $c>b, c-b$ must be $+1\iff c+b=?$
Btw, we can prove the following more easily:
$$\cos^2A+\cos^2B-\sin^2C$$
$$=\cos^2A+\cos(B+C)\cos(B-C)$$
$$=\cos A(\cos A-\cos(B-C))$$
$$=-\cos A(\cos(B-c)+\cos(B+C))$$
$$=-\cos A(2\cos B\cos C)$$
